# Implement IDbConnection in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, interface, idbconnection

I have a .Net core web application and .net core library. When using Dapper, I need to pass in a concrete class that inherits from `IDbConnection`. The problem is that in .Net Core `System.Data` is not a viable reference, it looks like they are doing away with it.

Is there a .Net replacement or a nuget package I can use some where. I need to connect to Microsoft Sql Server 2016

**Edit**

I attempted to make a .Net Standard Library to see if I could use `System.Data` that way. And I also could not add `System.Data` to the new project.

**Edit 2**

I found a nuget package System.Data.Common. This seemed to work it had the interface `IDbConnection` however I can't see a way to connect to SQL. I would have to make my own implementation of `IDbConnection`. So I am at a loss again.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add [System.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/) nuget package as dependency. It has

```
//
// Summary:
//     Represents an open connection to a SQL Server database. This class cannot be
//     inherited.
public sealed class SqlConnection : DbConnection
```

so you will be able to do

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;    // As of 2019 using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
...

using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    dbConnection.Open();
    // dbConnection.Execute(query, data);
}
```

Comment: Ahh, what a wild ride.

Comment: As of 2019, you should now use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` (available as a nuget package).

Comment: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient does not define IDbConnection.

Comment: It's still as System.Data.SqlClient for me using new .Net Core 3.1 project.

Comment: Maybe you don't have problem anymore but for other who found here. You should abandon IDbConnection and start to use DbConnection which is found from System.Data.Common namespace it is Abstract class which can be used quite similar as that interface.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
//create class for DBconnection
public class DBConnectionHelper
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DBConnectionHelper(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public IDbConnection ConnectToDatabase()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        try
        {
           // conn.AccessToken = new Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

In `startup` class:

```cs
services.AddTransient(db => new DBConnectionHelper(AppSettings.ApplicationDBConnString).ConnectToDatabase());
```

And in `apsetting.json`:

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
 "ApplicationDBConnectionString": "server=....;Database=....;user id=....;Password=...;",
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**